# Is it allowed to ask about which sources are reliable to get certain data?

Tags: discussion, acceptable-questions

In my case, I'm doing a research about cost of living in different countries.

But data I find is not consistent, different web pages I find give different measurements for that data.

So, I think it's worthwhile asking about a web page that is reliable in offering such data.

I understand that is not exactly an economics question, but I think it's neither an absolute offtopic one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our page has stricter rules than just having economics topic.

According to our rules laid down in the help center question should not be opinion based.

If you just ask what dataset is reliable you will likely get opinion based answers as what is reliable is subjective.

However, instead of asking what is dataset is reliable you can ask what datasets people use in let’s say 1Q and 2Q journals for the topic you are interested.

Such question would not be opinion based as it can be always objectively double checked that there are papers with this or that dataset in Q 1 or 2 journal.